# Can dynamodb use high-precision numeric strings as sort keys?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I need to store a high precision data into dynamodb, but I also need to sort using this field, but I don't get the desired result.

- If it is stored as N data type, the sorting result is correct
- If stored as S data type, it loses precision

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of precision you're after, but the [DynamoDB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html) say

> Numbers can have up to 38 digits of precision. Exceeding this results in an exception.
> Positive range: 1E-130 to 9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999E+125
> Negative range: -9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999E+125 to -1E-130
> In DynamoDB, numbers are represented as variable length. Leading and trailing zeroes are trimmed.

It specifically calls out the following:

> If number precision is important, you should pass numbers to DynamoDB using strings that you convert from the number type.

Comment: The source data is a numeric string, and I want to sort by this field, but I can't save it directly as a numeric type because of the limitations of Number in javascript, rather than the precision limitations of dynamodb.
But I found another way to solve this problem.
Thank you very much.